# How to create a runnable jar with the eclipse jdt API?

Tags: java, eclipse, jar, eclipse-jdt

When we are in Eclipse IDE and right-click on a java project, we have the option to export that project as a **runnable Jar file**.

It exists, thus, some code that uses the jdt API to accomplish this task.

I know the package used should be *org.eclipse.jdt.ui.jarpackager* but I couldn't find how.

Does anybody know something more?

To be clear, I'd like to start in my program (eclipse plug-in) with a JProject object and be able to save a jar file (and later load the same) in the workspace.

***EDIT:*** It's a programming problem. I don't know how to use the classes of *org.eclipse.jdt.ui.jarpackager* to transform a **JProject** in a **runnable Jar file**.

Comment: If this is an Eclipse plugin you are writing you use `Export > Plug-in Development > Deployable plug-ins and fragments`. The code must be written as an Eclipse plug-in. You just add the JDT plugins as dependencies of your plugin, they are not included in the exported plugin.

Comment: The problem is not the development of the plug-in itself. It's a programming problem. I don't know how to use the classes of _org.eclipse.jdt.ui.jarpackager_ to transform a **JProject** in a **runnable Jar file**.

Answer (score 0):

Solved by myself.

I simply extended the fatJarExportWizard and used it.